# Converting special characters { } into Json from Php

Tags: php, arrays, json

i am trying to create the json code below using php but putting curly braces in an array produces an error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{' in >/opt/lampp/htdocs/bulksms.php on line 23

```
 {

"properties": {
        "delivery_mode": 1,
        "headers": {}
    },

"headers": {},
"props": {},

}
```

Is there a way i can escape these characters (the curly braces) without putting them in a string. Below is the php code that i have so far.

```
$jsonData = array(
      'properties' =>  array(
          'delivery_mode' => 1,
          'headers' => {}
        ),

      'headers' => {},
      'props' => {},
    );
```

Comment: What output you expecting from this ?

Comment: You are mixing syntaxes of different languages. In php you need something like `'headers' => []` or `'headers' => new stdClass()`, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[PHP code demo](https://eval.in/762499)

```
$jsonData = array(
      'properties' =>  array(
          'delivery_mode' => 1,
          'headers' => (object) array()
        ),

      'headers' => (object) array(),
      'props' => (object) array(),
    );
print_r(json_encode($jsonData));
```

**Output:**

```
{
    "properties": {
        "delivery_mode": 1,
        "headers": {}
    },
    "headers": {},
    "props": {}
}
```